# How to identify a google docs element index?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have very little programming skills and am trying to make a simple proof of concept before hiring someone to code the entire thing.

I am creating a dynamic document based input form results.  I want to do two things that I just can't figure out:

*edit: The form data goes into google sheets. There is a table in the beginning of the document with info about the appointment.

1. I want take the word in a specific cell of the document's appointment info table and use it as the file name. However, I can't figure out how to identify the index of that cell's text.
2. Change the formatting of a heading at a specific index. I know how to insert formatted text, delete text, etc.  But can't figure out how to change the formatting of existing text.

I have tried every variation of .getParent(), .getChildIndex(), getNextSibling(), etc.

Here is the link to an example [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rAl9gnmAZL68KakgzJ3WbQKQ86tYvyLO0XZETreJNdQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Here are the some of the things I have tried to find the index in the cell next to the label "Psychometrist":

```
function findElement() {
  var foundTag = body.findText('Psychometrist');
  if (foundTag != null) {
    var tagElement = foundTag.getElement();
    var parent = tagElement.getParent();
    var parentLoc = parent.getParent().getChildIndex(parent);
    var parentTwo = parent.getParent();
    var parentTwoLoc = tagElement.getPreviousSibling();
    var parentTwoLocA = parentTwoLoc.
  } 

    Logger.log(tagElement);
    Logger.log(parent);
    Logger.log(parentLoc);
    Logger.log(parentTwo);
    Logger.log(parentTwoLoc);
}
```

I am completely lost here.  I just want to figure out how to tell the file-name code to get the text in that location, as the text will vary.

And also change the formatting of text in a specific location.

Comment: You're trying to run this in docs or in sheets? Because you said a "cell" indicating sheets) but you are also trying  to use "body" which is a docs term.

Comment: Your document seems to be a template with a lot of placeholders like "<<Smth>>". Perharps you want to index these placeholders to have quick access to them. If so, I recommend to use [bookmarks](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/bookmark) to have a single plain list of all placeholders positions. Otherwise you should check index with objects hierarchy with a lot of relations like "parent - child" or "sibling - sibling".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A Project to Help you Identify and Edit Tables and Cells in Google Docs from Google Apps Script

This project loads into your side bar and reads your document to look for tables.  When it finds tables in display all of the rows, cells, row indexes, cell indexes and cell text.  Each cell has a text box and a Save button which allows you to edit the cell text.  But you can also get just the indices to use in your own program.

You will have to create an html file named 'script' and load the script.html code into it and the rest of the code can go into the Code.gs file.  If you make separate project from the one you're working then you can run the onOpen and it will create a menu that won't bother any possible menus in your project.

Code.gs:

The function "findingTableCells()" generates a sidebar which utilizes a templated approach so that Javascript Functions can be developed in a less cumbersone method rather that trying to include into a string as though they were minified.  It also has tool tips included to help you identify the various indexes and table elements.

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Table Menu')
  .addItem('Find Table Cells', 'findingTableCells')
  .addToUi();
}



function findingTableCells() {
  var d=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=d.getBody();
  var numChildren=body.getNumChildren();
  var html='<html><head>';
  html+='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
  html+='<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">';
  html+='<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
  html+='<style>';
  html+='body{font-size:14px;font-family:calibri;}';
  html+='td,th{border:1px solid black;}';
  html+='.tblcell input[type="text"]{background-color:#ffff00;margin:2px 1px;}';
  html+='.tblcell input{margin:1px;}';
  html+='.tblcell a{text-decoration:none;}';
  html+='.childhdr{background-color:#00ffff;}';
  html+='.childhdr a{text-decoration:none;}';
  html+='</style></head><body><table>';
  for(var i=0;i<numChildren;i++) { 
    var child=body.getChild(i);
    if(child.getType()==DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<span class="childhdr">Child[<a href="#" title="Child Index">%s</a>]:</span><br />',i);
      var numRows=child.asTable().getNumRows();
      for(var ri=0;ri<numRows;ri++) {
        var numCells=child.asTable().getRow(ri).getNumCells();
        for(var ci=0;ci<numCells;ci++) {
          var cellText=child.asTable().getRow(ri).getCell(ci).editAsText().getText();
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<span class="tblcell">R:[<a href="#" title="Row Index">%s</a>]&nbsp;C:[<a href="#" title="Cell Index">%s</a>]:<input type="text" value="%s" id="%s-%s-%s" size="10" title="Editable Cell Text"/>',ri,ci,cellText,i,ri,ci);
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<input type="button" value="Save" onClick="saveCellText({child:%s,row:%s,cell:%s})" title="Saves Text using slightly different text style."/>', i,ri,ci);
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<input type="button" value="Bold" onClick="setCellTextStyleBold({child:%s,row:%s,cell:%s})" title="Bolds & Enlarges Text"/></span><br />', i,ri,ci);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  html+='<?!= include("script") ?>'
  html+='</table></body></html>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createTemplate(html).evaluate().setTitle('Finding Table Cells');
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function saveCellText(cObj) {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  body.getChild(cObj.child).asTable().getRow(cObj.row).getCell(cObj.cell).editAsText().setText(cObj.text).setAttributes(Normal1);
  return cObj;
}

function setCellTextStyleBold(cObj) {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  body.getChild(cObj.child).asTable().getRow(cObj.row).getCell(cObj.cell).editAsText().setAttributes(Bold1);
  return cObj;
}
```

style.gs:

The style.gs file just has a couple of simplistic style objects for demonstrating how one can change the style programmatically.

```
var Bold1={};
Bold1[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]=true;
Bold1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE]=14;
var Normal1={};
Normal1[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]=false;
Normal1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE]=10;
```

script.html

There's just two functions here, one that save any edits that you make in the cells at one style .  The other just bolds and enlarges the text. They both perform client to server communication with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

```
<script>
  function saveCellText(cObj) {
    var id='#' + cObj.child + '-' + cObj.row + '-' + cObj.cell;
    $(id).css('background-color','#ffffff');
    var txt=$(id).val();
    cObj['text']=txt;
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(cObj) {
      var id1='#' + cObj.child + '-' + cObj.row + '-' + cObj.cell;
      $(id1).css('background-color','#ffff00');
    })
    .saveCellText(cObj);
  }
  function setCellTextStyleBold(cObj) {
    var id='#' + cObj.child + '-' + cObj.row + '-' + cObj.cell;
    $(id).css('background-color','#ffffff');
    var txt=$(id).val();
    cObj['text']=txt;
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(cObj) {
      var id1='#' + cObj.child + '-' + cObj.row + '-' + cObj.cell;
      $(id1).css('background-color','#ffff00');
    })
    .setCellTextStyleBold(cObj);
  }
</script>
```

- [DocumentApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app)
- [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)
- [Enum ElementType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element-type)
- [Enum Attribute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute)

[Here's another approach](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/recent-scripts/finding-table-cells-in-google-docs-2?authuser=0) which stores all of the original attributes in a global array on the clientside.

Comment: [Here's another approach](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/recent-scripts/finding-table-cells-in-google-docs-2?authuser=0) which stores all of the original attributes in a global array on the clientside.